How to use `MCOPY`?
I'm a student who's learning smart contract develop. I want to write some assembly codes to solve this problem.
    function convert()
        public
        pure
        returns (bytes memory)
    {
        address WETH = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;
        bytes20 weth = bytes20(WETH);
        bytes memory path = "0x1b81d678ffb9c0263b24a97847620c99d213eb140000647606f6ad09dd4fae7656c688469eee5024d15a63";

        // Before:
        // 0x1b81d678ffb9c0263b24a97847620c99d213eb14 // address
        // 0x000064 // uint24
        // 0x7606f6ad09dd4fae7656c688469eee5024d15a63 // address

        assembly {
            // TODO: 
            // MCOPY?
        }

        // Expect:
        // return 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc20000647606f6ad09dd4fae7656c688469eee5024d15a63
        // 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2
        // 0x000064
        // 0x7606f6ad09dd4fae7656c688469eee5024d15a63
    }

The original path is "0x1b81d678ffb9c0263b24a97847620c99d213eb140000647606f6ad09dd4fae7656c688469eee5024d15a63", which is encodePacked by (address, uint24, address).
I want replace the first address with WETH address.
Is MCOPY opcode suitable for solving this?

One way to achieve this is by categorising the input and output in the form of the respective prefix and suffix.

Input

prefix:  address that you're replacing (i.e., 0x1b81d678ffb9c0263b24a97847620c99d213eb14).

suffix: the remaining portion (i.e. 0000647606f6ad09dd4fae7656c688469eee5024d15a63).



Output

prefix:  address of WETH (i.e., 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2).

suffix: the remaining portion (i.e. 0000647606f6ad09dd4fae7656c688469eee5024d15a63).




Here's the minimal code:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

contract BytesManipulation {
    function convert(bytes memory path) public pure returns (bytes memory) {

        bytes memory prefix = hex"C02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2";

        // Create a dynamic array to hold the suffix
        bytes memory suffix = new bytes(path.length - prefix.length);

        // Copy the suffix into the dynamic array
        for (uint256 i = prefix.length; i < path.length; i++) {
            suffix[i - prefix.length] = path[i];
        }

        // Concatenate prefix and suffix
        bytes memory result = abi.encodePacked(prefix, suffix);

        return result;
    }
}

OUTPUT:


Thank you sir, it works but not gas saving because of the loop.
I'm wondering how to solve that by using assembly which is more efficient.

Sorry, I don't have much exposure to assembly yet. But, I hope someone would help you out with that. Happy coding!

If you don't need the original path after modifying it, then the most efficient solution is to overwrite it. Like this:
    function convert()
        public
        pure
        returns (bytes memory)
    {
        address WETH = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;
        bytes20 weth = bytes20(WETH);
        bytes memory path = abi.encodePacked(
            address(0x1b81D678ffb9C0263b24A97847620C99d213eB14),
            uint24(0x000064),
            address(0x7606F6AD09dD4FAe7656c688469eEE5024D15a63)
        );

        assembly {
            let p := add(path, 0x20)  // pointer to first 32 bytes
            let x := mload(p)   // first 32 bytes
            x := or(weth, shr(160, shl(160, x)))   // overwrite address
            mstore(p, x)   // save to the same pointer
        }
        
        return path;
    }

If you need to keep the original path, we can make a copy with mcopy like this:
        bytes memory newpath;
        assembly {
            newpath := mload(0x40)   // newpath is a pointer to the variable

            let pathsize := mload(path)   // size in bytes

            let p := add(path, 0x20)  // pointer to first 32 bytes
            let x := mload(p)   // first 32 bytes
            x := or(weth, shr(160, shl(160, x)))   // overwrite address

            let newp := add(newpath, 0x20)
            mcopy(newpath, path, add(pathsize, 0x20))  // copy all
            mstore(newp, x)   // save to the new pointer

            mstore(0x40, add(newpath, add(pathsize, 0x20)))   // move free memory pointer
        }
        
        return newpath;
    }

I hope it's clear. Basically we copy all of it with mcopy(newpath, path, add(pathsize, 0x20)) then modify the first 32 bytes with mstore(newp, x).
